# Bordering text within reportlab

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I am working on an application in python that generates a pdf file using the reportlab library. How can I put borders around some text in there? The font color in the pdf is a certain color and I would also like some borders around the text.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether the text is inside a Paragraph flowable or inside Table flowable.

If text is inside Paragraph then add an attribute **borderColor = None** and change it accordingly.

If the text is inside Table flowable then add **Inner grid** and **Box**  property in TableStyle to add borders around the text.